# OpenGL - Changing blending modes using sprite batching

Tags: opengl, particles, blending, batching

I'm working on a game which uses sprite batching to render sprites efficiently where each sprite gets batched with its VBO data into a VAO every frame (containing vertex coordinates, texture data and color data). So far so good. I'm sorting them on the CPU and ordering the batch before each draw call according to render order to simulate z-ordering.

However, there's one problem: what do I do when I want to draw particles, for instance, which require a blending mode change? All of the sprites are drawn using `glDrawArrays` use the same blending mode, but for my particle data I want to change the blending mode. If I put the particles in the same batch then I won't have the ability to change it necessarily. My goal is to switch from normal blending (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) to additive blending (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE).

**1st solution:** use a separate draw call for every sprite and don't batch them at all. then for each call I can change the mode appropriately

**2nd solution:** add a z-coordinate to each sprite to do z-ordering automatically on the GPU using depth testing (this means I can render particles separately in their respective batches with ~2 calls -> +1 for sprites & +1 for particles) which will allow me to change blending modes.

Is there another way of approaching this problem? What am I missing?

Comment: What blend modes are you using? You may be able to get the same output with some shader or texture trickery.

Comment: I'm using GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE for glBlendFunc.

Comment: And what's the other one? You say that you need to change blend modes so we need to know what both are.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA.

Comment: It seems like it wouldn't be practical to do on the shader/possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633950/opengl-blend-modes-vs-shader-blending

Comment: That question relates to programmable blending, which is a bit more complex. If nobody has answered in a few hours time I'll write out one way you can do this.

Comment: So the blending can be non..programmable? It seems like it'll be complicated either way. Well thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your blending modes. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to switch between normal and additive blending?

Comment: Yes, that's all I'm trying to do.

Comment: @JeremiahCummings I would be nice if you could edit that into your question then. Switching between normal and additive blending can be done with shader trickery, but switching between blending modes in general can't be.

Comment: Yup, I just changed it to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Background**

OpenGL blend funcs are just a means of specifying a mathematical formula as follows:

- `src`: the output from your fragment shader.
- `dst`: the colour in the framebuffer.
- `sfactor`: multiply `src` by this.
- `dfactor`: multiply `dst` by this.
- And add the two results together.

(As a simplifying assumption I'm ignoring blend equation, blend func separate and multiple render targets, and also assuming that you don't care about destination alpha).

So if we look at your two blend funcs we see that they work out as follows:

```
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE)                  =  src * src.a + dst * 1
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)  =  src * src.a + dst * (1 - src.a)
```

The objective is to find a way to use a single blend func for everything.

---

I'm going to assume, for the purposes of this answer, that your fragment shader writes it's output to `gl_FragColor`.  If it doesn't, just replace any references to `gl_FragColor` in the remainder of this answer with whatever you do write to.

---

Let's repeat the two blend funcs again:

```
src * src.a + dst * 1
src * src.a + dst * (1 - src.a)
```

The only difference between the two is the value used for `dfactor`, and it's `(1 - src.a)` in the latter, so if we can modify our fragment shader to output 0 for `src.a` in the former case, then the two blend funcs become the same (because 1 - 0 = 1).

However, we see that `src.a` is also used as `sfactor` in both, so we can't modify `src.a` without also affecting that.

Let's see if we can find a way of modifying the fragment shader to remove that restriction.  Since we don't care about destination alpha we can just do this:

```
gl_FragColor.rgb *= gl_FragColor.a;
```

After having done that, the two blend funcs become:

```
glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ONE)
glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

Or:

```
src * 1 + dst * 1
src * 1 + dst * (1 - src.a)
```

So the only remaining thing is to find a means of setting `src.a` to 0 in the former case; something like this in your fragment shader:

```
gl_FragColor.rgb *= gl_FragColor.a;
if (altBlend) gl_FragColor.a = 0;
```

So we want `altBlend` to evaluate to `true` in cases where you use `GL_ONE, GL_ONE` blending, or `false` in cases where you use `GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` blending, and we have the result; we can now use a single blend func for all drawing:

```
glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Or:

```
src * 1 + dst * (1 - src.a)
```

And in cases where `src.a` is 0 this is exactly equivalent to:

```
src * 1 + dst * (1 - 0)
```

Or:

```
src * 1 + dst * 1
```

Or:

```
glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

---

So all that's remaining is how to set the value of `altBlend`, and how you do that is entirely up to you.  You could set an additional vertex attrib that you pass along to your fragment shader, you could bind an additional texture and sample from it for the different types of objects, or you could do something entirely different; it all depends on which is most appropriate for the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks for this, awesome explanation! I'll implement this. I suppose I could also change src.a to 0 on the texture just for the particles which would be called "premultiplied alpha" right?

Comment: Actually wait, nevermind, thinking of something else. That wouldn't work since I'm looking at the fragment already defined right when a particle is rendered to do the blending not the texture itself. This solution is surpisingly simple & elegant!

Comment: This assumes that when a shader processes a fragment in the VBO that it has already processed every other VBO (or sprite, object, whatever i'm drawing) before it in correct order, so it's cumulative and I can apply blending correctly? (not sure how the GPU would do parallel processing/layered rendering any other way)

Comment: That's generally the case when drawing alpha objects, yes.

Comment: Am I missing something? If I change src.a to 0 then the eqn src * src.a + dst * (1 - src.a) becomes = dst and I don't get any of the source color at all. If my goal is to convert the equations to be equal it isn't possible. I need to keep src.a because it could be the alpha value for the other particles which is not just 1 or 0 but could be any value in between.

Comment: Since the only thing I can modify is the src value in the shader I can't touch the dst values in the colour buffer so there is no other way to make the equations equal. This is ok for GL_ONE, GL_ONE  but not for GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE?..

Comment: "Traditional blending with glBlendFunc can't be replicated in a shader. Blending requires sampling the destination framebuffer before modifying it, which isn't something that can be done on current hardware."

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, my solution was to just change blending modes in my sprite batcher by keeping track of the indices where blending modes change and then call glDrawArrays as many times as I need whenever the blending mode changed. They're still batched, but the chunks are as small as the gaps between blending modes.

Comment: I started to write an answer, but then realized that Le Comte du Merde-fou already described anything. Do `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`, and then `gl_FragColor.rgb *= gl_FragColor.a; gl_FragColor.a *= blending_mode;`, where `blending_mode = 1` will result in normal blending and `blending_mode = 0` will result in additive blending. Why don't you want to do it?

Comment: Doesn't that blend mode make it src*1 + (1-src.a)*dst where dst is whatever is in the color buffer. The problem w/ this is gl_FragColor.a will always be 1? So I'll never get transparency.. (in the case where blending mode is 1)

Comment: Just try it and it will work. I've used the trick countless times. You also might want to know that the resulting image will have *premultiplied alpha* (as if you did `color.rgb *= color.a` on normal image; look it up). It doesn't matter when rendering to the screen, but after rendering to a texture you might want to do `color.rgb /= color.a` to revert the changes.

Comment: Edit: whoops, yeah nvm ok will do. my blend mode was wrong for sfactor.